# How to avoid flickering with Angular Universal app?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular app with SSR (Angular Universal) configured with `initialNavigation: 'disabled'` in Router and with a Service injected with `APP_INITIALIZER` in the `AppModule` that gets data from an API and then the Router execute `initialNavigation` manually from this Service.

Furthermore the data received is stored with [`PersistenceService`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-persistence) and It gets from route resolvers in a component to do another API call with this data before load the component.

The problem is that If I have `initialNavigation: 'disabled'` in the Router, the web loads SSR version, flick and then loads client version.

*AppModule*

```
export function getAreas(areaService: AreaService) {
    return (): Promise<any> => { 
        return areaService.getAreas();
    }
}
...
providers: [
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: getAreas, deps: [AreaService], multi: true}
    ],
```

*AreaService*

```
getAreas(): Promise<any> {

        const router = this.injector.get(Router);

        const promise = this.contentService.getAreas()
            .toPromise()
            .then(data => {
                this.memory.set('areas', data);

...
router.initialNavigation();
```

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlanCategoryResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private contentService: ContentService,
        private router: Router,
        private memory: MemoryService
    ) { }

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<any> {

        return this.contentService.getCategoryPlans(this.memory.get('areas'));
    }
}
```

> PersistenceService is used inside MemoryService.

So I need avoid the flickering and the route resolver gets the data before load the page. Because I need to do another API call with this data in the resolver. If the `initialNavigation` is not `enabled`, the flickering happens.

What can I do to avoid the flickering and keep the data of the `APP_INITIALIZER` Service to get the route resolver data?

Answer (score 0):

Angular docs state. https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

> One of enabled or disabled. When set to enabled, the initial navigation starts before the root component is created. The bootstrap is blocked until the initial navigation is complete. This value is required for server-side rendering to work.

If there is any way to not require the call before initialNavigation I would explore that option.  If you need the call before initialNavigation you might be able to prime the angular ssr with a provider in express before the server side rendering happens.  You can do this with middleware and a provider when you call the engine.

```
ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: 'data', useFactory: () => dataFromMiddleware, deps: [] }
    ]
  });
```